# Custom login page for a product which is built using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication

We have deployed an ASP.NET product that works only with windows authentication. The product team has not provided any custom login page and hence the user has to enter his credentials only in the popup that the browser throws.
My question is though the product has not given any login page, can we develop a login page to authenticate the user and send the authentication details to the application?

Comment: if your target application supports API or a web service then you can authenticate your users locally and send the authenticated users' details to the target application.

Comment: The product has API/Web Services. They are used for writing bespoke applications. My requirement is to just send the authentication token to the target ASP.NET product and from there it takes on..

Comment: Your target web service needs to have an authentication function to check the token before process the rest of the request. if it doesn't, then do you have an access to add one yourself ? or maybe someone who's maintaining the target application for you?